# MY_Controller class not found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The main thing i want to solve is to check user session when somebody want to access admin panel. I've created MY_Controller class and placed it in library.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Session {

public $logged_in = FALSE;

public function  __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->is_logged_in();
}

public function is_logged_in()
{
    $logged = $this->userdata('user_id');
    $this->logged_in = ($logged) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function sessdestroy() {

    $this->session->sess_destroy();

}

}
```

This is my login page. I've created a button that redirects to admin panel (dashboard) just to test if the session check works.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

}

public function index() {

    $this->load->view('view_login');

    if(isset($_POST['redirect'])) {

    redirect('admin');

    }
}


}
```

This is the admin controller where i check if the user session exists.

```
class Admin extends MY_Controller {

function construct() {

    parent::__construct();

}


function index() {

    if($this->is_logged_in()) {

    $this->dodadi_destinacija();

    }

    else redirect('login');

}

}
```

BUT i got this error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\UserPanel\application\controllers\admin.php on line 3
```

Can you tell me your thoughts about my coding solution for the given problem please :)

Answer (score 7):

1. You need to extend the `CI_Controller` class instead of `CI_Session`
2. You should place `MY_Controller` under `application/core/` folder instead of `application/library`

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter introduced a new folder called `core` where the libraries that doesn't require loading lives. The original CI_Controller class is one of them, so if you want the automagick pick up your `MY_Controller.php` file you should place it under `application/core` too.

When in doubt, check the extended class's original version under `system` directory and mirror that under `application`.

(Also in your first code example, i think you meant to extend `CI_Controller` not `CI_Session`)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on a project as I'm learning CodeIgniter. My solution was to, to use your project as an example, `require_once('MY_Controller');` at the top my new Controller.

That way I didn't have to move my file to the core and I could keep it in my directory of Controllers.