# Calling a controller in another controller

Tags: codeigniter, class, controllers

I need a hand here guys, I am confuse on how I will be placing my files for my code to work out. I had 2 controllers named

```
ex: 
controller1.php
controller2.php
```

which I want all my functions in `controller1.php` accessible in controller2.php so I write

```
class Controller2 extends Controller1 { 

}
```

which I had applied what I had understand here [Calling a Controller function in another Controller in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647112/calling-a-controller-function-in-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

But I am getting an error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controller1' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bla\application\controllers\Controller2.php on line 3
```

Then I had search for any possible solution then i had found out that i had to place `Controller1.php` in the core folder but I am getting the same error..[MY_Controller class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000312/my-controller-class-not-found)

I am using the latest version of codeigniter framework.

What I had missed? How?

Comment: I think every controller is auto loaded. why don't you take the instance of another controller class to your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the **file** and **class** to "MY_Controller" if you placed it into the "/core" folder. The prefix is important (which you can set in your config, by the way). Also, make sure, that in MY_Controller, you extend the CI_Controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

You can then access this core-Controller with your other Controllers like this:

```
class Controller1 extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: This explains what I had in mind.. But how do i tweak the name of the file and name of the class e.g. `MY_Controller` because for some reason, I want my file to be relevant to what was on the code

Comment: Well, the core controller has to be named that way (<prefix>_Controller) for CodeIgniter to find it. As far as I know, the only thing you can change is the prefix

Comment: You don't have to extend the base controller if not needed. Just put your class in `MY_Controller.php` and it will be loaded.

Comment: Aah, that's true, it's not a necessity to extend the CI_Controller. Thanks for that clarification :) In my cases, I always extended the base controller

Answer (score 0):

`Controller1` will be auto-loaded and be able to use for extending if you place it inside `application/core/MY_Controller.php`.

Otherwise, you have to use `require`:

```
require APPPATH . 'controllers/Controller1.php';
class Controller2 extends Controller1 { }
```

Comment: I think this also a good one and more readable but the drawback is that you have to include the file in all your class.. but thank you for the input @anvoz coz if the above code will not work then I would definitely use this one..

Comment: If you need to use `require` in a lot of files then `Controller1` should be a base controller defined in `MY_Controller`.