# Class 'MY_Controller' not found after download from webserver

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Might be somehow copy of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000312/my-controller-class-not-found) but the choosen answer is not giving me a resolution.

I have copied site built on codeigniter to localhost from server and I get this error message. I have checked the case (altough Windows is non-case-sensitive) in the files and I am using `MY_Controller` as classname, filename and including file as well, made screenshots, see images:
1. Extending MY_Controller

[image: Extending MY_Controller]

2. File structure

[image: file structure]

3. MY_Controller class header

[image: MY_Controller class header]

The file is in the `core` folder, but I still get this error message.

What am I doing wrong and what could be the solution?

Comment: put the code of MY_controller from core folder

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: application/core. If core folder not exist, the create new one.

Comment: As I described in my question, the file MY_Controller.php is in the core folder

Comment: Is `$config['subclass_prefix']` contains `'MY_'` in config/config.php?

Comment: Yes it is just like classname and filename

Comment: have you thought to use XDebug to trace the program execution - this is usually quite insightful for these types of errors.
you have a file named 'admin_controller.php'  could this file be failing and causing problems?  also i presume you are using codeigniter version2.1.4?? older version did not have the CI_ prefix.

Comment: I am using >2.1.4, and it works fine on the Linux server. I have downloaded it and configured on localhost and it gives this error.
Haven't used XDebug so far, maybe i should try it now.
And admin_controller.php should not be the problem, that is another class used in the admin module only.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php file in the root folder of the site check that the $system_path and $application_folder variables are correct. For example, I keep mine outside of the publicly accessible path, at the same folder depth as my public_html and so these for me are set as:

```
$system_path = '../system';

$application_folder = '../application';
```

If you've copied it from a web server then it's possible that something similar has been setup or perhaps an absolute path has been specified.

Comment: The site has been uploaded to the webserver by me. The file structure is the same, all these subfolders are in root.

Comment: And do both hosting setups have the same relative DocumentRoot?

Comment: I have adjusted the root path in the config file so relatively the root of codeigniter index file is the same